# "Rendering of admin template [path to template] failed"

Tags: plugin-development, php, errors

I've got a php script that is called when the user is editing the category. However, although the page renders fine for the most part, at the point where the image upload button should appear, I'm seeing this message:

> Rendering of admin template
>   /home/site/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/folder/subfolfer/admin/file.php
>   failed

What are the likely causes for this error in this one site? Other sites are processing this fine?

THe site has PHP version 5.2.16
THe site has WP version 3.0.5

Comment: the code would help

Comment: Do a search over your whole site's codebase for 'rendering of admin template' or parts thereof...it doesn't seem to be a string defined anywhere in the wordpress codebase. Even the word rendering alone is rare. So this might come from one of your plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an error related to the HeadSpace2 plugin, see.
http://urbangiraffe.com/support/topic/rendering-of-admin-template-failed-2
http://urbangiraffe.com/support/topic/rendering-of-admin-template-failed-continued

Perhaps the plugin has template support which you've enabled but not created the appropriate file for in the theme? I have no idea, i don't use the plugin, just thinking out loud..

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks t31os. Always appreciate your help. I don't use headspace, but the issue is the same.